# Standalone script unable to write to a document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am making my first effort at a webapp. My sample code is super simple. I read the content from CNN and post it to my webapp url.

However I want to save the resulting text to a document so I can view it in a browser. My script is included below.

```
function doPost(e) {
  var body = e.postData.contents.toString();
  DocumentApp.openById('1ZvbBqQpBbi4NeA604bMOJRSWiEgNtn_09qFaIVObUZo').getBody().clear();
  DocumentApp.openById('1ZvbBqQpBbi4NeA604bMOJRSWiEgNtn_09qFaIVObUZo').getBody().appendParagraph(body);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(body);
}

function postData(){
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  var page = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://edition.cnn.com/').getContentText();
  var pageBlob = Utilities.newBlob(page)
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/<some id>/exec', {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : pageBlob
  });
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

The problem is the 2 lines with `DocumentApp` at the beginning. If I run the `postData` function it returns some HTML containing:

> "The document is inaccessible. Please try again later"

and neither line is executed. In other words, the document doesn't even clear.

If I comment out the second line, the document does clear. If I comment out the first line, nothing happens in the document and I get the same error message.

I would have thought if it was a permissions issue I would not be able to clear the document. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: A little more information:

If I replace body with `"hello world"` it works. So there is something about the body variable it does not like.

Comment: Don't forget to `saveAndClose()` if you need to flush pending changes. Alternately, why not `const doc = DocumentApp.openById(...); doc.getBody().clear(); doc.getBody().appendParagraph(...);`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found the problem. If I load yahoo.com instead of cnn it works fine. CNN is 3 times larger - over 1.5Mb. It seems to be a character length issue.

Comment: It is very interesting. There are quotas of Google Drive files https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603?hl=en and UrlFetchApp limitations https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations The body request have to be about 50Mb.

Comment: @oshliaer If my understand of the situation is correct, I think that OP's issue is that when the large text is put to Google Document using methods of DocumentApp, even when the size is about 1.5 MB, the error occurs. In my environment, I had also confirmed this situation. So when I put the large string value to Google Document, I put them by separating the string value. As another situation, when I put the large HTML value as HTML, I put them by Drive API. In this case, the HTML value can be directly put to Google Document. I thought that OP needs the former.